# Error: NavigatorView's page stack is empty in onsenui

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm developing mobile application using onsenUI and facing this problem when navigating to pages in stack.

When moving from first page to second page, we normally use `pushPage()`.
From second page to first page, we use `popPage()`. But when moving from third page to second page using back button and from second page to first page, I'm getting

```
Error: NavigatorView's page stack is empty
```

I tried using `resetToPage()` but still getting this error..

Here what I tried.

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/62kS6ZguT3LWQwurrQxW?p=preview)

**UPDATED:**

When navigating from services.html to index.html, I'm getting this error in console. Please check this. When I poppage from third page to second page, then second page to first page, I'm getting error as navigation view page stack is empty

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ons-back-button>` already perform a popPage itself, so there is no need to do `ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()` in it. With that it will try to delete 2 pages from the stack when there is only 1, so it warns that the page stack is empty when trying to perform the second popPage. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using <ons-back-button> in the header and I use <ons-button>cancel</ons-button> for footer. In footer, I'm facing the problem. especially when I use button event

Comment: The code you shared in Plunker is working for me, the back-button and the normal button. Can you include the rest of the code?
If the error is about stack empty, probably the problem is still related to make 2 popPage instead of one or something similar.

Comment: Please try like this in plunker that I shared. Click First Page button, it will go to services.html, Click Second page button, it will go to menu.html. Now, click cancel button from menu.html and click back button from services.html...when I m getting first page, I m getting this error in console..pls Try with firebug. Again if i click first page button, I m getting page is not found error

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any other error. I just deleted the ng-click and it works perfectly for me. Check the code in Codepen better:
http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/wBEmaW

Comment: Please see my updated question with the screenshot bro. I m not using single html file to use ons-template. In this case, I m using multiple html files. If it is single html file, this problem wont occur

Comment: Once again, can you please remove `ng-click="myNavigator.popPage();"` from your `<ons-back-button>` and try again? The project I shared with you in Codepen is exactly the same as yours, but using `<ons-template>` instead of different files and removing that ng-click. You can copy the content of "services.html" from there to your project, if you want.

Comment: Sorry! Copied codepen code and it is working fine. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @FranDios-Hello i am getting this error when i click ons-back-button twice.can it be possible to resolve it by preventing back button clicked twice?

Comment: @JigarMakwana If I don't remember wrong, last versions of OnsenUI prevent back-button to trigger twice. Try to update to 1.3.13 or so if you are using and older one.

Comment: @FranDios-it says navigator page stack is empty when pressed twice.can you help me for this?

Comment: @FranDios-i am using onsenui - v1.2.1 .

Comment: @FranDios-can you tell me how can i update my existing onsen io in my project?

Comment: @JigarMakwana That happens because it tries to pop 2 pages when there is only 1 page. OnsenUI 1.2.1 is quite old (we have already 1.3.13 and 2.0-beta), so I fear you need to make some changes to update it. Install it with `bower install onsenui` and fix the errors that comes up. You can check the [changelog](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see if there is any breaking change.

Comment: @FranDios-yes friend,but thing is that i didnt know how to update onsen in my project.are you getting me?please help me

Comment: @JigarMakwana What other information do you need apart from what I already said? 1 - Download the new version (you can use bower to do it). 2- Plug it to your app (substitute onsenui.js file if you use that one). 3- Read the JavaScript console and see what fails. 4- Try to fix those errors (checking the changelog version may help you).

Comment: @FranDios-means just download and replace the existing files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95671/discussion-between-fran-dios-and-jigar-makwana).